# Ubuntu USB from Canonical shop keeps crashing

Tags: system-installation

About a week or so ago, I bought a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS USB from the Canonical shop. I just got it in the mail, but when I get about a minute into it, the installer crashes and takes me to the desktop. Any suggestions?

```
Specs:
PC Name: Dell Inspiron 3668
RAM: 8GB
Hard Drive: 1TB
Processor: (several, I don't know how many) Intel Core i5 @ 3.00GHz
```

Since posting I have also selected the "Check disks for defects" option, and it says that it found 2 errors, but I do not know how to check what errors it found.

In the past I have had many Linux distributions running, but I live in the middle of nowhere and lost my USB (nearest place to buy a USB/any writable media is very far away), so I ordered one with Ubuntu already on it. I do not believe that it is writable, only readable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post hardware specifications.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the post with my specifications, as well as some more information.